# What is the equivalent Haskell type for C99 bool when using FFI?

Tags: haskell, c99, ffi

I have a library which uses C99 `bool` data type and I would like to call it via FFI.

What is the corresponding type for C99 bool in Haskell? In [Foreign.C.types](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-C-Types.html) there are CInt, CShort etc, but no CBool.

If there is no "correct" type for `bool`, what is a safe alternative type to be passed in a function expecting a `bool`?

An alternative approach would be to modify the C library but I would like to keep it intact.

Comment: I ended up modifying the library to use ints instead of bools. It was an in-house library, so it was quite trivial to patch. Anyway, this is an interesting problem at its own. Hope the base library may be extended with bool support in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `sizeof(_Bool)` is implementation-defined in C99 (see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.2.5, 6.2.6 and 6.5.3.4/4), the obvious portable solution is to call such functions via wrappers that use `int` instead of `bool`. Alternatively, if you don't care about portability, you can check the documentation of your compiler to find out what is `sizeof(_Bool)` on your platform and use the corresponding FFI type.

My guess for the reason of `CBool` being absent from `Foreign.C.Types` is that the underlying C implementation is not expected to support all features of C99. One very widely-used compiler (MSVC) does not support C99 at all.

Comment: I don't know if that makes sense as a reason. Obviously `CBool` would only be used when interfacing with C code that used `bool`, in which case you're assuming the existence of a compliant compiler. I expect a more likely reason is that `CBool` is more obscure and less often used, so no-one's found it necessary to write the support yet.

Comment: Since it's *implementation-defined* it could be any size at all, even on a C99 compliant complier--and could vary between compilers. Any FFI to C would be hard-pressed to figure this out automagically and *safely*, and the Haskell FFI is no exception.

Comment: @jpaugh Well, `sizeof(int)` is also implementation-defined in C. However, we can call functions with `int` parameters from Haskell since the C ABI for a target platform is specified by the platform vendor. The problem is that some vendors chose to ignore C99 extensions. A reasonable solution would be to treat `_Bool` similarly to `unsigned char` in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, C99 does not define exact size of `_Bool` type (and `bool` is mapped to `_Bool`). The only thing you do know about it is that it is large enough to hold values `0` and `1`. So, its binary representation is compiler-dependent, that's why, I guess, it is not present in the FFI support library.

The following program, being compiled with GCC 4.7.2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d", sizeof(bool));
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
% gcc -std=c99 -o test test.c
% ./test 
1
```

So, `bool` seems to be mapped to `char` in GCC. What you will see depends on your compiler.

Because of this, I think, if you want complete portability you'd better write a wrapper for your C function which will take plain `int` and pass it to the function with a type cast.

Comment: Following the same reasoning none of `CInt`, `CLong` would exist as those don't have exact size requirements either. All we know about e.g. `int` is that it must at least support values from -32767 to 32767.

Comment: @LucDanton, underlying types for `CInt` and `CLong`, however, are supported by **all** compilers, with no exceptions. This cannot be said for `bool`, because it is C99 extension, and some of the most used compilers do not support C99 at all. Obviously, decent FFI implementation should not rely on existence of ideal compiler supporting all recent standards.

Comment: Then that should be the answer, not what you put. My comment was a rhetorical device to demonstrate the flaw in the argument.

Comment: I agree that the representational issue is entirely a red herring. It's not a problem that `_Bool` might change size, we just need `CBool` (or whatever) to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between having a `bool` as parameter and having a `bool` result type.

---

I'm quite sure sure, that C99 bool was introduced (and is different from all other basic values), because the pre-C99 BOOL was not a good enough **return** type of functions:

There needs to exist an in-memory-representation of such a variable, at least 1 byte, but...

1. The handling of booleans on assembler level is done via FLAG-dependent gotos. (see && and ||)
2. It should be possible to use the faster bitwise & and | instead of && and || on booleans, which needs the bool to be 1 bit.
3. The return-value of a function should be able to use the FLAG register (on some machines) 
   instead of beeing forced to use 1 bit of an INT register or even to use any zero/nonzero int in an INT register.

Because of 3., IMHO,
unless we consider the ABI (Application Binary Interface) of the C99 bool usage on each platform, there won't be any direct solution for this. It might be easier to patch the haskell compiler to wrap each imported/exported C function that has/should have the C99-bool result type.

---

If I remember correctly, `int` is the safe alternative for most basic C types in the **parameter** list of a C function. But CChar will most likely do the same (or better) for bool, too. You might want to read about that variadic parameter feature `,...)`, which is used by `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [hsc2hs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/utils.html#writing-haskell-interfaces-to-c-code-hsc2hs), you can just do this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

type CBool = #{type bool}

cFalse, cTrue :: CBool
cFalse = 0
cTrue = 1
```

and you can also use the `toBool` and `fromBool` functions in [Foreign.Marshall.Utils](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Utils.html#g:3) to convert between `CBool` and `Bool`.

The magic is in `#{type bool}`, which tells `hsc2hs` to choose a Haskell numeric type which is the same size as the C type `bool`.  On my machine, this turns out to be `Word8`.

Answer (score 0):

The `base` library has `Foreign.C.Types.CBool` as of version `4.10.0.0`, corresponding to `ghc-8.2`.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Foreign-C-Types.html#t:CBool